# Using Timeline to jump into detail page of app

Tags: c#, uwp

In my app, I have a top menu, a ‘list page’ and ‘detail page’. The information on the list page is passed as a parameter to the detail page.

I am trying to use Timeline to jump back into the detail page of my app, by creating an ActivationUri in the detail page and then the associated code in App.xaml.cs in OnActivated. However, when I click the item in Timeline, the app just navigates to the default home page. I think the issue is that the app is not ‘remembering’ the passed parameter when I use Timeline.

Any advice on this, if it is even possible, would be much appreciated. Thanks.

App.xaml.cs:

```
DetailPage detailpage = new DetailPage();
var mylink = detailpage.pageid;

if (uriArgs.Uri.Host == mylink)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(DetailPage), uriArgs);
}
```

DetailPage.xaml.cs:

```
public string pageid;

    public DetailPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo    (NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var MyClickedItem = (MyModel)e.Parameter;
        Title.Text = MyClickedItem.Title;
        pageid = MyClickedItem.Id;

        // Get channel and create activity.
        UserActivityChannel channel =     UserActivityChannel.GetDefault();
        UserActivity activity = await     channel.GetOrCreateUserActivityAsync("details" + MyClickedItem.Id);

        // Set deep-link and properties.
        activity.ActivationUri = new Uri("my-app://" +     MyClickedItem.Id);
        activity.VisualElements.DisplayText = Title.Text;
    }
```

Comment: Could you try to debug your app to see whether your app OnActivated event triggered? It should be your code's issue, if you could provide a simple sample to let me see the issue, it would be easier to resolve it.

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT The OnActivated event is definitely triggered, and when I debug the app, `uriArgs.Uri.Host` has the expected value, but the variable `mylink` has a value of `null`. I will work on a quick sample and comment here again.

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT Here is a [sample](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Am9fgKcdTsLhgXy4Un3SMPpXn5Zs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I clarify that the `DetailPagePage` in your sample is corresponding the `DetailPage` in your above code.

The reason why the `stuff` variable( `mylink` in your above code) is null is that you create a new `DetailPagePage` class object which is not the same `DetailPagePage` object you navigated to when you click the GridView item. When you create a new `DetailPagePage` object, this new `DetailPagePage` object's `pageid` is not assigned a value, so it is null.

You can change the `pageid` property to a static property of the `DetailPagePage` class, then you can access the same `pageid` in the App.xaml.cs,

In the `DetailPagePage` you just need to change the `pageid` to static,

```
public static string pageid;
```

Then, in your `OnActivated` method of App.xaml.cs, since the `uriArgs.Uri.Host` make lowercase the `Title`, when you compare to the pageid, you need to call the `ToLower()` method. So the `OnActivated` method would looks like this:

```
protected override async void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    await ActivationService.ActivateAsync(args);

    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
    {
        var uriArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;

        if (uriArgs != null)
        {
            //DetailPagePage detailpage = new DetailPagePage();
            var stuff = DetailPagePage.pageid;

            if (uriArgs.Uri.Host == stuff.ToLower())
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(DetailPagePage), uriArgs);
            }
        }
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
}
```

After that, you also need to modify your navigation parameter `uriArgs` and the `DetailPagePage`'s `OnNavigatedTo` method, since the `uriArgs` can not be convert to a `MyModel`, you maybe need to use the navigation parameter data to create the `MyModel` object with same info to dispaly them.

---**Update**---

> you maybe need to use the navigation parameter data to create the `MyModel` object with same info to dispaly them.

This is to say, you can create a new `MyModel` object which has the same property value as the `MyModel` object you clicked in the `OnActivated` method, then pass this object in the `Navigate` method, so the `OnActivated` method will be like this:

```
protected override async void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    await ActivationService.ActivateAsync(args);

    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
    {
        var uriArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;

        if (uriArgs != null)
        {
            //DetailPagePage detailpage = new DetailPagePage();
            var stuff = DetailPagePage.pageid;
            MyModel parameter = null;
            if (uriArgs.Uri.Host == stuff.ToLower())
            {
                switch (stuff)
                {
                    case "Title1":
                        parameter = new MyModel
                        {
                            Title = "Title1",
                            Subtitle = "My Subtitle 1",
                            Description = "My Description 1 goes here."
                        };
                        break;
                    case "Title2":
                        parameter = new MyModel
                        {
                            Title = "Title2",
                            Subtitle = "My Subtitle 2",
                            Description = "My Description 2 goes here."
                        };
                        break;
                    //Some other case      
                }
                NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(DetailPagePage), parameter);
            }
        }
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. I'm just not sure what you mean in your last paragraph when you refer to using "the navigation parameter data to create the MyModel object with same info to dispaly them."

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check it. You can also have your own logic to handle this to display the same info in the UI.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer and for all of your help, I understand how to write the code much better now.